# Should I send letters of recommendation for a faculty job application that doesn't require them?

Tags: job-search, tenure-track

I am applying to a faculty position. The application announcement says they require a cover letter, CV, research statement, and teaching statement, but does not mention letters of recommendation. Should I request that my references send letters anyways? Would the search committee ask for them later in the application process?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to AcademiaSE. You should specify the country. Many European countries, for instance, do not have the concept of Letters of Reference.

Comment: Sometimes, LORs are only required for shortlisted applicants.